# Merge unrelated branches branches from SVN to Git conversion

Tags: git, svn

I converted a project from SVN to Git. This project had a few branches which I think where just copied into /branches. That now related to detached branches that have no connection to the master branch.

In the Graph it looks like this

```
                             HEAD
Master    o--------------o----o

Branch A       o----o
```

Is there any possibility which lets me achieve that the Master has a connection to the detached branch?

```
                             HEAD
Master    o--------------o----o
           \
Branch A    o----o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to rebase A to `master` (assuming you want `branch A` to origin from `master`, as opposed to be *merged* in `master`: it is not clear from your diagram where is master HEAD, the most recent commit)
See How to re-apply commits on top of unrelated branch?

```
git rebase A1 A2 --onto M --committer-date-is-author-date
```

With:

- `A1`: oldest commit from `branch A`
- `A2`: current A HEAD (most recent commit)
- `M`: an old commit from master you want `A` to be created from

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated my Question with the HEAD

Comment: @MarcSchaetz OK. The answer remains the same. Let me know if you have any issue applting it.

Comment: In your code snippet there is A1 mentioned twice. Should one of them be A2?

Comment: @MarcSchaetz Indeed, I have edited the answer accordingly.